# How to get to next list in the List<List<Node>> when particular condition is satisfied

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<Node> nodes` and each `node` in `nodes` have a variable called `Interest` associated with it.

```
public static List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
for (int i = 0; i < Program.n; i++)
        {
            //int densityrandom = generateRandom();
            Node n = new Node(Interest3);
            Program.nodes.Add(n);
        }
```

While class Node is as Follows:

```
 public class Node
{
    public int Density { get; set; }
    public InterestProfile P1 { get; set; }
    public List<Edge> adjnodes { get; set; }


    public Node(InterestProfile a)
    {
        adjnodes = new List<Edge>();
        P1 = a;
    }
}
```

For some object `Interest1` of type `InterestProfile` there is an array associated with it like

```
Interest1 = new InterestProfile(array1);
```

So, if you do something like `nodes[0].P1.InterestArray[0]`, it will give me first element in the `array1`.

Now here is my actual question:

I am splitting up the list `nodes` according to user input into list of list of Node. Thus, if `nodes` have 100 elements in it, it will be split up into 10 lists and all those lists will stored in one list.

*This is something I have in mind:*

```
List<List<Node>> smallList = new List<List<Node>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            for(int k=0; k < smallList.Count; k++)
            {
            if (list[i].P1.InterestArray[0] > 5 && smallList[k].Count != 10)
            {
                smallList[0].Add(list[i]);
            }
            else smallList[k+1].Add(list[i]);
        }
```

and so on by checking for all 5 elements in an array associated with particular node. However, when `smallList[0]` reaches limit of 10, I want to start adding elements from `nodes` in some other `smallList[i]`. When all the values of particular `InterestArray[j]` are checked for all nodes in `nodes`, then only it should move to checking `InterestArray[j+1]`. How can I program this in c#? Is my implementation correct and if yes can it be improved?

I know question is quite confusing. Please ask me if anything is difficult to understand. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: aside: why did you split your List<Node> up?

Comment: @markmnl I dint get you.

Comment: What was wrong with `List<Node>` nodes, why did you split the list up into many small lists `List<List<Node>>`? It seems unnecessary and further complicates things like the algorithm you are attempting.

Comment: Also I think you could better describe what you are trying to achieve - it is confusing.

Comment: It is because I want nodes from List<Node> to be arranged in small list of size 10 in such a way that all nodes with InterestProfile[i] value greater than 5 are together. I am kind of sorting them on the basis of value of InterestProfile[i]. I hope it clears the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the `List<List<Node>>` data structure why not simply query your existing `List<Node>` for the nodes you want when you need them?

e.g.

Old School:

```
var interestingNodes = new List<Node>();
foreach(Node node in nodes)
{
    foreach(int i in note.InterestArray)
    {
        if(i > 5)
            interestingNodes.Add(node);            
    }
}
```

Using `List<T>.FindAll()`:

```
var interstingNodes = nodes.FindAll(node => node.P1.InterestArray.Contains(5));
```

Or in LINQ:

```
var interstingNodes = from node in nodes
                      where node.P1.InterestArray.Contains(5) 
                      select node;
```

Comment: And can I extend this implementation for all elements of InterestArray[]??

Comment: what do you mean? what do you want to get?

Comment: The code that you have return only considers first element in the array InterestArray. I want to check the condition of "if greater than 5" for all of the elements on InterestArray[]. Like for InterestArray[1],InterestArray[2],InterestArray[3]...

Comment: yes that is easy, updated my answer, you can use another nested loop or `Array.Contains()` or LINQ's `IEnumerable<T>.Any()`

Comment: Thank you for updates. Is my implementation about checking if size of 'interestingNodes' list is greater than 10 and if yes then adding elements in new list seems correct?

Comment: there are some things wrong with you implementation in the question, e.g. you are always checking the fist element of InterestArray: list[i].P1.InterestArray[0], perhaps you meant k where the 0 is. adding check for size to the ones in my answer would be trivial using the AND operator: if(I > 5 && node.InterestArray.Length > 10)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51600/discussion-between-dotnetnewbie-and-markmnl)

Comment: Hey.. thank you for all help. What I want is.. Suppose I found 10 elements for which value of InterestArray[0] is > 5. Now these 10 elements are in interestingNodes list as per your implementation. Now suppose there is some 11th element from 'nodes' that satisfy similar condition if InterestArray[0] > 5. This 11th element should go in some another var interestignNodes 2 = new List<Node>(). And so on..